# split larger file into smaller files: help regarding 'split'

Tags: shell, awk, split, gawk

I have a large file (2GB) which looks something like this:

```
  >10GS_A
  YTVVYFPVRGRCAALRMLLADQGQSWKEEVVTVETWQEGSLKASCLYGQLPKFQDGD
  LTLYQSNTILRHLGRTLGLYGKDQQEAALVDMVNDGVEDLRCKYISLIYTNYEAGKD
  DYVKALPGQLKPFETLLSQNQGGKTFIVGDQISFADYNLLDLLLIHEVLAPGCLDAFP
  LLSAYVGRLSARPKLKAFLASPEYVNLPINGNGKQ 
  >11BA_A
  KESAAAKFERQHMDSGNSPSSSSNYCNLMMCCRKMTQGKCKPVNTFVHESLADVKAV
  CSQKKVTCKNGQTNCYQSKSTMRITDCRETGSSKYPNCAYKTTQVEKHIIVACGGKP
  SVPVHFDASV
  >11BG_A
  KESAAKFERQHMDSGNSPSSSSNYCNLMMCCRKMTQGKCKPVNTFVHESLADVKAVCSQKKVT
  CKNGQTNCYQSKSTMRITDCRETGSSKYPNCAYKTTQVEKHIIVACGGKPSVPVHFDASV
  >121P_A
  MTEYKLVVVGAGGVGKSALTIQLIQNHFVDEYDPTIEDSYRKQVVIDGETCLLDILDTAGQEEYSAMRD 
  QYMRTGEGFLCVFAINNTKSFEDIHQYREQIKRVKDSDDVPMVLVGNKCDLAARTVESRQAQDLARSYG
  IPYIETSAKTRQGVEDAFYTLVREIRQH
```

I wanted to split this file into smaller files  based in the delimiter ">" in such a  way that, in this case, there are 4 files generated which contain the following text AND ARE NAMED IN THE FOLLOWING MANNER:

```
10gs_A.txt
11ba_A.txt
11bg_A.txt
121p_A.txt
```

AND THEY CONTAIN the following contents: 
10gs_A.txt

```
>10GS_A
YTVVYFPVRGRCAALRMLLADQGQSWKEEVVTVETWQEGSLKASCLYGQLPKFQDGD
LTLYQSNTILRHLGRTLGLYGKDQQEAALVDMVNDGVEDLRCKYISLIYTNYEAGKD
DYVKALPGQLKPFETLLSQNQGGKTFIVGDQISFADYNLLDLLLIHEVLAPGCLDAFP
LLSAYVGRLSARPKLKAFLASPEYVNLPINGNGKQ
```

11ba_A.txt

```
>11BA_A
KESAAAKFERQHMDSGNSPSSSSNYCNLMMCCRKMTQGKCKPVNTFVHESLADVKAV
CSQKKVTCKNGQTNCYQSKSTMRITDCRETGSSKYPNCAYKTTQVEKHIIVACGGKP
SVPVHFDASV
```

... and so on. 
I am aware about separating a larger text file using the split command in linux, however it names the files created as temp00, temp01, temp03. 
Is there a way to split this larger file and have the files named as I want? 
What is the split function to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `gawk` you can do -

```
gawk -v RS='>' 'NF{ print RS$0 > $1".txt" }' InputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using an awk script to split mybigfile

splitter.awk

```
BEGIN {outname = "noname.txt"}

/^>/  { outname = substr($0,2,40) ".txt"
        next }

      { print > outname }
```

If you want the separator row in the output, then use the following:

splitter.awk

```
BEGIN {outname = "noname.txt"}

/^>/  { outname = substr($0,2,40) ".txt"}

      { print > outname }
```

Then run this file

```
awk -f splitter.awk mybigfile
```

Comment: Hi. This worked. Although, I have one more concern, which is this: The content of generated files doesn't begin with >10GS_A, or >11BA_A, as I had wanted it to. Can this be achieved in this splitter script?

Comment: Edited answer and added code as per your needs. Also added more tags based on the solution.

Comment: could this be adapted to split after a certain number of lines?